# Netlogo: SHP offset world display

Tags: gis, netlogo

I'm loading an urban grid SHP file for a city simulation, but the display is offset from the world window, as can be seen in this image:

[image]

The red arrows show unintended extra space and blue arrows an area that is occupied by more urban grid but is not covered by the world window. This is the setup code:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor [225 226 228]]
  load-dataset

  draw-ins_industr20_a
  draw-curva_nivel20_l
  draw-cuerpo_agua20_a
  draw-corriente_ag20_l
  draw-carretera20_l
  draw-camino20_l
  draw-camellon20_a
  draw-manzana20_a
  draw-movilidad

  copy-values-to-patch
  fitness
  set threshold 4
  reset-ticks
end
```

This is the load-dataset procedure:

```
to load-dataset
  set ins_industr20_a-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/ins_industr20_a.shp"
  set manzana20_a-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/manzana20_a.shp"
  set curva_nivel20_l-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/curva_nivel20_l.shp"
  set cuerpo_agua20_a-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/cuerpo_agua20_a.shp"
  set corriente_ag20_l-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/corriente_ag20_l.shp"
  set carretera20_l-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/carretera20_l.shp"
  set camino20_l-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/camino20_l.shp"
  set camellon20_a-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/camellon20_a.shp"
  set area_cultivo20_a-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/area_cultivo20_a.shp"
  set movilidad-dataset gis:load-dataset "datos/Movilidad.shp"
end
```

and the associated prj file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bo69icfv1ozeend/manzana20_a.prj?dl=0)

As a result, the simulation outputs urban growth in the gray area of red arrow, which is wrong. How can I fix this issue so the simulation does not take into account the gray area, and align all the urban grid to the limits of the world display?

Comment: Can you show your `load-dataset` procedure? Do you have a .prj file associated with your .shp file?

Comment: I have just edited the thread with the requested info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
set envelope gis:load-dataset "data/polygon.shp" 
gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of envelope
```

polygon.shp equals the extents of view to be displayed in the world window. Then, to eliminate the extra gray space, play with max-pxcor and max-pycor values in Model Settings dialog box until window view matches the extents of the shp file. The envelope command guarantees that the extent of the shp file will always be shown.